# How to convert a remote branch into a local one in Eclipse using Bitbucket?

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I'm kind a newbie on Bitbucket so I have a lot of doubts.

I share an Eclipse project between two different computers. I have pushed the project from one computer to the Bitbucket repository using the Eclipse plug-in. Now when I go to the other computer I have fetched the repository that is saved on Bitbucket, and it has created a new remote tracking branch on my Eclipse local repository.

My problem comes when I want to merge that branch with the local branch, I have no idea how can I do that

Anyone could help me?

ps: sorry if the problem or the situation is not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the section "[Pulling New Changes from Upstream Branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch) ":

a `git pull` is a `fetch` + a `merge`.

> Right-click on a project in the Package Explorer and select `Team > Pull` or right-click on a repository in the Git Repositories view and select `Pull` to pull new changes from the upstream branch your local branch is tracking.

The section "Fetch and Pull" of the [Egit tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/) says as much:

> When cloning remote repositories, Git creates copies of the branches as local branches and as remote branches.
>   A `Fetch` operation will update the remote branches only.
>   To update your local branches as well, you will have to perform a Merge operation after fetching.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the solution. It works perfectly!